# Microsoft reporting server

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reporting

i want to learn everything from scratch about reporting server,,can you tell me the practical steps needed for that,,,Is there any video tutorial for studying about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several screencasts on DNR TV.  I found them very useful for getting started.  They are at

http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=26

http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=27

http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=28

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about SSRS I'd start here http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/reporting-services.aspx

[Professional SQLServer Reporting Services](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0764568787) was a good book to get me going.

Essentially SSRS are SQL data driven reports represented in an xml format (.rdl).
They are  hosted on and run on a web report server. As well as being rendered in html you can render them in excel, pdf, tiff and more out of the box.

There is an introductory video [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aafHygddNqc)

Answer (score 0):

This is the reference that I used: [http://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-Server-2005-Reporting-Services/dp/0072262397/ref=pd_bbs_sr_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1237550043&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0072262397).

Comment: John's working for this one - he has a video posted.  I used the above reference to learn all I needed to know and then abandoned SSRS because it was A) way more complex to deploy than other solutions and B) far more expensive.  I use the DevExpress reporting solution now.

Answer (score 0):

The best book on the subject is the "hitchhikers guide to sql server reporting services 2000"

Although this appears to deal with an older version of the product, what you have to remember is that RS was not released with SQL 2000, but was rush released in SQL2K Sp2 before appearing in SQL 2005 a few months later, so the product differences are minor

This will serve as a good foundation

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Hitchhikers-Reporting-Services-Microsoft-Windows/dp/0321268288